# Need Display Validation Error Message for row Drop down when Corresponding row check box=unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have check boxes and drop downs in each row in the Table,if i try to select Corresponding row drop down when that row check box unchecked it should Display an Error validation Message. Drop down should be  able to Configure only After Check Box =Checked.
and There is an apply Button too but in this code i am not added
Please Help Me ,and I have tried this.

```js
function validate() {
  var prefix = "chkdd";
  var e1;
  for (var i = 1; e1 = document.getElementById(prefix + i).length; i++) {
    if (e1.checked == "") {
      alert("Please enable check box");
      e1.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if (!e1.checked == "") {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

function selectOrgChildRec(ctrl) {
  $(ctrl).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlighted');
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: #66CDAA;
}

tr {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkdd1" onclick='selectOrgChildRec(this)' /></td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL1" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL2" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL3" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL4" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL5" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL6" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkdd1" onclick='selectOrgChildRec(this)' /></td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL1" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL2" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL3" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL4" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL5" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL6" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkdd1" onclick='selectOrgChildRec(this)' /></td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL1" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL2" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL3" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL4" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL5" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL6" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkdd1" onclick='selectOrgChildRec(this)' /></td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL1" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL2" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL3" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL4" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL5" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DDL6" onchange="validate(this)">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code. E.g. `</script </head>` should be `</script></head>` Also, HTML `id` attributes should always be unique. Use `class="DDL1"` instead. I highly recommend properly formatting your code and using a [code linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)).

Comment: @Daan I corrected syntax errors ,can i know the solution now?

Comment: ID attributes should always be unique. Also, you're passing a parameter to `validate(this)`, but function `validate()` doesn't use any parameters. I can give you the solution, but StackOverflow isn't a platform where people do work for free. Don't get me wrong though, I am trying to help you. You should probably check your [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), as it doesn't seem right.